# SQLite, how to apply function to each cell in a column and then perform IN operation on transformed values?

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to set up a query to apply a function on cell values for a column prior to performing an IN check or rather, match rows between table two tables where a column's cell values in a table are a substring of the other table's column of the same data type, specifically Strings.

I need something like,
`'A' IN ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')` from `'A' IN ('A|B', 'C|D')`.

What it comes down to, is the ability to say whether A from Table 1 is in Table 2.

```
Table 1  Table 2
-------  --------
A        A|B
B        C|D
C
D
```

Comment: Do all cells in the second table have exactly two values with exactly one character?

Comment: @CL. No, they are actually just place holders. They are usually 10 characters long.